# React state management in npm module

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-state-management

My goal here is to have an npm module that exports a set of useful components to various applications in my company.

The components will need to have fairly complex shared state. Much of this state the apps won't care about, but some of it they will. The apps will also need to be able to change the state of the components via dispatches or some mechanism.

Is there a recommended way to do this using Redux or hooks, or whatever? I could not find examples or tutorials for this specific design question.

Comment: Are you wanting the "changed states" or the "default states" of the components to be shared across different platforms?

Comment: The changed states.

Comment: You will likely need some sort of backend service to store and supply the front end with. I don't think what you are looking for is React state management which would be internal app management. What it sounds like you are looking for it external state management. A way to go about what you are trying to do is have some backend service say firebase supply your React state management to then determine the UI. You will also need to have the state saved/sent to firebase to keep track of that UI.